# Including Previous Project in Angular 2 Website

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web, html5-canvas

A while back, I created a game in Javascript that uses the HTML canvas element to render images. I now have a personal website developed with Angular 2 and was wondering what the correct approach would be to embed my game on my website. From what I understand, I would have to place the Javascript from my game in its own file because Angular 2 deletes the script tag from HTML (so I can't just put the game straight in the .html file). So with the game logic in a .js file and the HTML elements in a file associated with a component, how should I link the two together?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the script inside of your index.html, so that Angular doesn't touch it. If you need to reference any globally injected objects inside of your TypeScript code, you can add "declare var [variableName]: any". You can get more info [here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/javascript-libraries-in-a-typescript-application-revisited/).

Answer (score 0):

you can have one script loaded per view and this will reload when going to page again

```
constructor() {
  document.getElementById("testScript").remove();
  var testScript = document.createElement("script");
  testScript.setAttribute("id", "testScript");
  testScript.setAttribute("src", "assets/js/test.js");
  document.body.appendChild(testScript);
}
```

hope it helps.